# A network-related or instance-specific error?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

Hi i deployed my application on clients machine an it is working fine but at first when i click on any button it gives me error present in the screen shot:[image]

I am going round and round but not reach at exact issue ,i am using sql server 2012,can anyone explain me what is the actual reason behind this ??

Comment: http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Comment: enable on server FW UDP ports 1433-1435

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved as doing followings

1- Go to All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager
2- Double click the SQL Server on the right pane
3- On the Log On page check the service status below, if it stopped then click the start. 
4- Once it turns to running try to connect your database againg. I have solved it doing this just a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is only one possibility among many, but the first thing I would check given you are confident that the target database does, in fact, exist as configured is to ensure there's not an application firewall blocking access.

I would also ensure that named pipes as a protocol is enabled on the server.

Comment: named pipes are enabled  but i have to check for firewall port rule for port 1433

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check for you:

- firewall settings (is port 1433 open?)
- is TCP/IP a valid method of connecting (you can check that in SQL Server Configuration tool)
- does it allow remote logins?
- is it reachable via SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @SaadAhmed from the machine it's installed or from machine your application is installed on?

Comment: a machine where my application installed on